# Hibernate Create OneToMany instead of OneToOne

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, one-to-one

I don't understand why this code create OneToMany instead of OneToOne
Can somebody tell where i made mistake.    I have got 2 class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column(unique=true)
@Id
private String login;
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String city;
private int age;
private Sex sex ;
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//@JoinColumn(name= "user_details")
private UserProfile userProfile;
```

Second class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profile")
public class UserProfile {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long Id;
    @Id
    private String user_login;
    private String user_interestings;
    @OneToOne//mappedBy= "userProfile")
    @MapsId
    private User user;
```

Here is image, how it end in MySQLWOrkbench
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuoC6.png)

Thanks for help.

Comment: Use @JoinColumn instead of mappedBy

Comment: @Alien Can you tell something more cuz i'm not sure if I understand you

Answer (score 1):

Use `@JoinColumn` with the foreign key in `UserProfile` as your Database design

```
public class UserProfile {
    ...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_login")
    private User user;
}
```

And your primary key for both table confusing. If you need both table use same primary key then map this way. Here both table primary key is `id`. You don't need `user_login` column then in `UserProfile` table.

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    ...
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private UserProfile userProfile;
}

public class UserProfile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long Id;
    ...
    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private User user;
}
```

Comment: Still as result I getting OneToMany

Comment: I don't understand how it's possible,  multiple entry exist in database, for both share same primary key

Comment: How you can identify you are getting OneToMany result ?

Comment: I'm using MySQLWorkBench Reverse Engineer

Comment: @NowakAdam Ok should mention your problem is MySQLWorkBench Reverse Engineer  table generation.  That is MySQLWorkBench  problem your relation are just fine

Comment: Pretty strange, Please could you check one more time my code:
https://pastebin.com/4XythAHY
Maybe i'm blind and don't see something important